# Jqgrid: How can i add validation fuction to a spesific search toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with a search toolbar. I want a date column in search toolbar 
 to have validation because it can only search in the certain format like yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy/mm/dd hh-mm-ss, otherwise it catches error.

when the input in the search toolbar is something like 2017/12, i want it to either show error message or automatically add 01 and make it '2017/12/01' so that it can search without getting a system error.

I was guessing that i can do that by javascript since i have validation function for data editing using EditClientSideValidators. but i dont know how i can do that for data searching.

thank you for reading my question. looking forward to your answers.

Comment: In order to get appropriate answer, please specify jqGrid version used?

Comment: If im not mistaken, its 1.8.16 since it says in my code * jQuery UI Progressbar 1.8.16

Comment: @momotaro: You used "jqgrid" as the tag for your question. Please answer **which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid**. Three typical alternatives, which you have today: 1) [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, which last released version is 4.14.1; 2) commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov and which last released version is 5.2.1; 3) the usage of old jqGrid in version <=4.7.

Comment: Can you help me with finding which version im using? I didnt download jqgrid to the local machine.. i was adding a new page to an existing web application with ASP.NET by Visual Studio so I guess it was already in there. all i found is jquery-ui.css and some other css files for jquery....